# How to calculate velocity based on acceleration and friction

Tags: javascript, game-physics

I am making a breakout game, I want the ball to slow down as it gets closer to the paddle.

I have acceleration vector `a`, and velocity vector `v`.

I update the velocity as:

```
v += a * delta;
```

Now how can I add friction that will decrease velocity?

Comment: This should probably be in the Physics stack exchange but anyway, unless you are trying to actually code this. If that is the case what have you tried?

Comment: v = (a * delta)/t; and not v = a * delta; unless t=1 of course

Comment: delta is the time since last update, what do you mean buy `t`?

Comment: So what is the value of the timestep t? I thought delta just meant change in acceleration. Is that change constant or does it depend on position? What is causing the acceleration/deceleration in your case?

Comment: acceleration is constant, what do you mean by timestep t?

Comment: A few years ago I wrote a bit of code in Processing to calculate something similar. Basically the position determines the force on the particle/planet, this force determines the acceleration or change in velocity and the change in velocity determines the new position. The is repeated and so the particle's position is updated constantly as it orbits for example a larger mass such as a sun. https://github.com/shanegibney/KeplerOrbitProcessing/blob/master/Kepler006.pde

Comment: Actually looking at it again, you have v = a*delta that is velocity equals change in acceleration but that is not correct, acceleration is change in velocity. The change in acceleration is called jerk incidentally.

Comment: I've updated @ShaneG

Comment: The timestep is important because is sets the time for this change. Does the change happen every second or 0.1s or 0.01s?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198014/discussion-between-eguneys-and-shane-g).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of friction you're trying to take into account.

If we are talking about the mechanic friction it can be added as

```
v = (a - f) * delta;
```

where `f` is some kind of friction coefficient.

In other cases (like aerodynamic friction which depend on the square of current velocity) the dependency could be more complex, for example velocity at some moment of time [1] would look like

```
v[1] = a * delta - k * v[0]^2 / 2;
```

where `delta` would be the difference between time 1 and time 0.

**UPDATE**

> I want to slow the ball as it gets closer to the paddle, Is that aerodynamic?

I think this situation does not relate to some real natural circumstances and you can use some artificial kind of slowdown. For example:

```
v = a * delta - Math.sign(a) * Math.min(k / d, maxBrake)
```

where

- `k` - some friction coefficient
- `d` - the distance between the ball and nearest paddle
- `maxBrake` - limiting factor in order to not to decrese velocity too much when the ball is right near the paddle.

This is not the only solution but of possible ones. There is more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: I want to slow the ball as it gets closer to the paddle, Is that aerodynamic?

Comment: But i don't have a friction vector i can't just subtract from `a`, i have a friction coefficient.

Comment: I didn't use vectors in my equations

Comment: Ok, what if acceleration is negative, and v is going negative wouldn't subtracting f just help the velocity go more negative aka going faster?

Comment: I've got what you mean. See my updated answer - I took acceleration sign into account

Comment: Note friction between surfaces in constant and not dependant on how fast you are going. But friction with the air or in a fluid usually called the drag force is dependant on the velocity.

Answer (score 0):

Simply multiply the velocity by a friction coefficient:

```
v *= k;
```

k is between 0 and 1, higher the less friction.